# Google bigquery SQL statement in Power BI

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, powerbi

I have an SQL code that works in Google BigQuery, but when I input the SQL code into Power BI, I receive an error message: 'Details: ODBC: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (70) Invalid query: Column name global_trade_item_number is ambiguous at [5:5]'.

Can you see what's wrong with the code?"

```
 WITH
  sale_data AS (
  SELECT
    d_date_order,
    store_site_id,
    selling_entity_id,
    selling_entity_type,
    global_trade_item_number,
    number_of_items,
    receipt_line_amount,
    consumer_spend_amount,
    store_sale_amount,
    margin_amount,
    store_identifier
  FROM
    `ac16-p-conlaybi-prd-4257.consumer_sales_secure.f_sale_receipt_line_day`
  WHERE
    d_date_sale >= "2023-11-01"
    AND selling_entity_type = "Special" ),
  store_data AS (
  SELECT
    store_identifier,
    store_name
  FROM
    `ac16-p-conlaybi-prd-4257.store.d_store` ),
  item_data AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `ac16-p-conlaybi-prd-4257.item.d_item` )
SELECT
  sd.d_date_order,
  sd.store_site_id,
  sd.selling_entity_id,
  sd.selling_entity_type,
  sd.global_trade_item_number,
  sd.number_of_items,
  sd.receipt_line_amount,
  sd.consumer_spend_amount,
  sd.store_sale_amount,
  sd.margin_amount,
  sd.store_identifier,
  st.store_name,
  id.*
FROM
  sale_data sd
JOIN
  store_data st
ON
  sd.store_identifier = st.store_identifier
LEFT JOIN
  item_data id
ON
  sd.global_trade_item_number = id.global_trade_item_number
```

Comment: don't use id,* which causes the problem and use aliases for all columns that are equal like global_trade_item_number

Comment: Thank you very much, @nbk for your quick response; it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Posting's @nbk recommendation as a solution for better visibility for the community to do not use "id.*" and use aliases that have the same column names:

> don't use id.* which causes the problem and use aliases for all columns that are equal like global_trade_item_number